# Shell can run the command but ZSH can't

Tags: bash, zsh

Inside my project folder if I use Bash and run `. ./setantenv.sh`, it works.

But in the same folder if I use ZSH and try to run `. ./setantenv.sh`, it results in `./setantenv.sh:4: = not found`

ZSH doesn't have any issues to run all the other commands. But it seems that it doesn't recognise the first `.` before the `./AnyCommand.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
OWN_NAME=setantenv.sh 
if [ "$0" == "./$OWN_NAME" ]; then
  echo * Please call as ". ./$OWN_NAME", not ./$OWN_NAME !!!---
  echo * Also please DO NOT set back the executable attribute
  echo * On this file. It was cleared on purpose.
  chmod -x ./$OWN_NAME
  exit
fi
PLATFORM_HOME=`pwd`
export -p PLATFORM_HOME
export -p ANT_OPTS="-Xmx400m -XX:MaxPermSize=128M"
export -p ANT_HOME=$PLATFORM_HOME/apache-ant-1.9.1
chmod +x "$ANT_HOME/bin/ant"
export -p PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
echo Setting ant home to: $ANT_HOME
ant -version
```

Any help?

Comment: bash and zsh syntax is different. Can you show your script? Seems like at the line 4 syntax is incorrect for zsh.

Comment: This is the line 4:
if [ "$0" == "./$OWN_NAME" ]; then

Comment: The double equals is a Bash extension, I guess maybe zsh doesn't like that? Try with a single equals sign in the comparison.

Comment: But that specifically has a `#!/bin/bash` shebang so you get what you should expect.

Comment: No, @tripleee, the script was sourced, so the shebang is just a comment.

Comment: I'm commenting on what's realistic to expect, not on whether it actually worked (which also it obviously didn't).

Answer (score 2):

`if [ "$0" "==" "./$OWN_NAME" ]; then`

or

`if [ "$0" = "./$OWN_NAME" ]; then`

rewrite like this when runs `zsh`.

Comment: ... or in any other non-Bash/ash/csh shell.

Comment: Don't assume `[` can *ever* use `==`; always use `=` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) is the latest POSIX specification for `test` and its alias, `[`.  as you can see, there's no `==` in the whole page.

freebsd *test(1)* man page says:

```
COMPATIBILITY
     For compatibility with some other implementations, the = primary
     can be substituted with == with the same meaning.
```

but zsh has `[` builtin:

```
% for sh in sh bash mksh zsh; do $sh -c "printf '%-5s- ' $sh; which '['"; done                                                                                
sh   - /bin/[
bash - /bin/[
mksh - /bin/[
zsh  - [: shell built-in command
```

... and zsh's version does not do `==`.  from *zshbuiltins(1)* (only the outer brackets on the second synopsis line are actual syntax, the rest is [*BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)):

```
   test [ arg ... ]
   [ [ arg ... ] ]
          Like the system version of test.  Added for compatibility; use
          conditional expressions instead (see the section `Conditional
          Expressions').  The main differences between the conditional
          expression syntax and the test and [ builtins are:  these
          commands are not handled syntactically, so for example an empty
          variable expansion may cause an argument to be omitted; syntax
          errors cause status 2 to be returned instead of a shell error;
          and arithmetic operators expect integer arguments rather than
          arithmetic expressions.

          The command attempts to implement POSIX and its extensions where
          these are specified.  Unfortunately there are intrinsic
          ambiguities in the syntax; in particular there is no distinction
          between test operators and strings that resemble them.  The
          standard attempts to resolve these for small numbers of
          arguments (up to four); for five or more arguments compatibility
          cannot be relied on.  Users are urged wherever possible to use
          the `[[' test syntax which does not have these ambiguities.
```

btw, the error message you got says `= not found` because zsh uses leading `=` for filename expansion.  from *zshexpn(1)*:

```
'=' expansion
   If a word begins with an unquoted '=' and the EQUALS option is set, the
   remainder of the word is taken as the name of a command.  If a command
   exists by that name, the word is replaced by the full pathname of the
   command.
```

apparently, there's no command named `=` anywhere in your `$PATH`. :)

```
% echo =ls
/bin/ls
% echo =fubar
zsh: fubar not found
% echo ==
zsh: = not found
```